# Distribution of Increments of a fractional Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion

According to my Textbook, a fBm Process $B_t$ has the same distribution as its increments:

$(B_{t+h}^H-B_t^H)_{t\geq 0} \stackrel{d}{=}(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$

To proof this, note that both sides are centered Gaussian Processes. Hence it is enough to show that they have the same covariance i.e.:

$Cov(B_{t+h}^H-B_t^H,B_{s+h}^H-B_s^H) = \frac{1}{2}(t^{2H}+s^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H})$

But I am not able to proof this.
So far I have:

$Cov(B_{t+h}^H-B_t^H,B_{s+h}^H-B_s^H) \\
=E((B_{t+h}^H-B_t^H)(B_{s+h}^H-B_s^H)) \\
=\frac{1}{2}\left(|(t+h)-s|^{2H}+|t-(s+h)|^{2H}-|(t+h)-(s+h)|^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H}\right) \\
=\frac{1}{2}\left(|(t+h)-s|^{2H}+|t-(s+h)|^{2H}-2|t-s|^{2H}\right)$

How do I continue from this or did I already make a mistake on the way ?

Comment: Can't be. For $H=1/2$ the [fractional BM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion) is a standard BM and we know that $B_{t+h}-B_t\sim N(0,h)$ for all $t\ge 0\,.$ On the other hand, $B_t\sim N(0,\color{red}t)\,.$

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that I messed up the indices. It should actually be $B_{t+h}^H-B_{\mathbf{h}}^H$. Now it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I messed up the indices. It should be:

$(B_{t+h}^H-B_{\mathbf{h}}^H)_{t\geq 0} \stackrel{d}{=}(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$

Now we can derive the desired result:

$Cov(B_{t+h}^H-B_h^H,B_{s+h}^H-B_h^H) \\
=E((B_{t+h}^H-B_h^H)(B_{s+h}^H-B_h^H)) \\
=\frac{1}{2}\left(
|t+h|^{2H}+|s+h|^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H} \\
-|t+h|^{2H}-|h|^{2H}+|t|^{2H} \\
-|h|^{2H}-|s+h|^{2H}+|s|^{2H} \\
+|h|^{2H}+|h|^{2H}-|h-h|^{2H}\right) \\
= \frac{1}{2}\left(|t|^{2H}+|s|^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H} \right) $